# Probability of pralines in a box

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Milk  and  Dark chocolate  pralines  are  randomly   placed  into  boxes  containing  a  total  of 25 pralines.
The colour of each praline is determined by a random mechanism so that on average, 60% of all pralines are dark.

(a)  Let the random variable M denote the number of Milk Pralines in a box. What is the distribution of M?

(b)  What is the probability that all chocolate pralines in one box are of the same type?

(c)  How many boxes need to be selected to have a chance of >90% to have at least one box with at least 15 Milk Pralines?

So far I believe I have managed to understand b). However a) and c) is a bit more difficult for me. What do they mean by asking the distribution?

***What i got till now:***
25 Pralines total per Box, 60% are Dark Pralines.

```
       D= Number of Dark pralines/box 

       n=25                

       p=0.6
```

b) $P[D=25]+P[D=0]={25 \choose 25}p^{25}(1-p)^{0} +{25 \choose 0}p^{0}(1-p)^{25}$

c) $p'=P[M\ge15]= {15 \choose 15}p^{15}(1-p)^{0}= 1-P[M\le14]$ which equals to 0.000470184.

Then $P[X\ge1]=1-P[X=0]= 1-{m \choose 0}p'^{0}(1-p')^{m}= 1-0.999529816^{m} $
Then I'd just use logarithm to find m

$$1-0.999529816^{m}\gt0.9$$
$$0.1\gt0.999529816^{m}$$
$$ln0.1\gt mln0.999529816$$
$$\frac{ln0.1}{ln0.999529816}\lt m$$

```
The m= 4896.04, SO I'd have to go through 4896 boxes to 
get a box with at least 15 Milk Pralines?
```

I think my answer is wrong, do I really have to go through 4896 boxes?
Have I been using the right methods?

And I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain a) for me.

Comment: in the last step you are dividing with a negative so you need to reverse the inequality

Comment: Overlooked that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

With regard to (a), you're already using the answer there to solve (b) and (c).

It's simply the binomial distribution ([mass probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function)) of $25$ objects with $p=0.4$:

$$P(M = k) = {25 \choose k}(0.4)^{k}(1-0.4)^{25-k}.$$

Comment: So that's basically a)? I didn't really understand the Q but thanks

Comment: Yep ... you already knew it, it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

a) $M\sim Bin(25,0.4)$

According to my calculator,

b) $p(M=0)+p(M=25)=2.843\times10^{-6}$

c) $p(M\geq15)=1-p(M\leq14)=1-0.9656084819...$

So you should have $$n>\frac{\ln0.1}{\ln0.9656...}=65.79$$
Therefore $n=66$